# Align instructions div tag under textbox

Tags: html, css

All,

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/k2AMG/7/

I am trying to avoid fixed widths in the CSS and align the divs in this fashion, but am not able to do so:

```
Your name    Textbox
             Please check the name
Work email   Textbox 
             Email should have a valid format
Job title    Textbox
             Job title should have only alphabets
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/k2AMG/11/

::Edit:: fixed demo

::Edit 2:: added CSS and HTML to post for future reference

**CSS**

```
.data_item{
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   display: block;
}

label
{
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.left {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
}

.right {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.right span span {
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Clarification: created two classes to separate the two sides, **.left** and **.right**, and added a style to the span of the .instructions div to display as a list-item (so they can displace like a regular html list would, why? Because it is a clean, responsive drop that displaces naturally without the need to add margin or padding that might displace with any other element around and thus less maintenance.).

**HTML**

```
<div class="data_item">
    <div class="left">
        <label> Your name </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span>
           <input type="text" />
           <span class="instructions">Please check the name</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="data_item">
    <div class="left">
        <label> Work email </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="item">
           <input type="text" />
           <span class="instructions">Email should have a valid format</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="data_item">
    <div class="left">
        <label> Job title </label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="item">
           <input type="text" />
           <span class="instructions">Job title should have only alphabets</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your rule for instructions in your css is missing the '.' before 'instructions'

Comment: you're totally right, left it there from the original demo, thanks for catching that. (removed it as it is not needed)

Comment: You could accomplish the same thing with much less markup. See http://jsfiddle.net/k2AMG/14/

Comment: @kelly you're totally right but the thing with that solution is that it doesn't properly isolate both regions and instead just squishes everything together with some margin acting as a divisor for the instructions text, that does not leave space for future improvement and if any other element is added in between it will need to be reformatted to make it work, so maintenance is an issue. Like a table, i see it as more proper to isolate both sides to leave space for future, pain free, changes. But either way works, really.

Comment: I guess it just depends on what you're going for, maintenance or performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/k2AMG/9/